# JSON object properties are undefined

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, undefined

I'm getting a JSON object back from an AJAX call and logging the result like this:

```
console.log(response);
```

And this is the response logged in the console:

```
{"filename":"new.jpg","orientation":"vertical"}
```

However, when I

```
console.log(response.orientation);
```

I get a response that it is undefined.

Most of the answers I've read indicate that an array was returned instead of an object and that response[0].orientation should work, but that is not the case here. When I assign the same array to another variable in the console:

```
var obj = {"filename":"new.jpg","orientation":"vertical"}
```

Then obj.orientation returns the correct value.

I'm creating the JSON object in PHP:

```
$response=array('filename' => $newfilename, 'orientation' => $orientation);
$response=json_encode($response);
echo $response;
```

Is it apparent why the properties are showing undefined?

Comment: if your response is a string you'll have to pass it through `JSON.parse` before you can access properties. also, [there's no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: can you post your code about how your sending ajax request and success function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either put:

```
header("Content-type: application/jason");
```

in the PHP, specify `dataType: "json"` in the AJAX call in the JavaScript, or call `JSON.parse`.

Comment: JSON.parse (or $.parseJSON in jQuery) did the trick. I don't know why it wasn't in the several tutorials I read... Thank you!

Comment: Seems to be a common problem, hardly a day goes by that we don't see someone ask essentially the same question.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to parse your string to get a proper JSON object.
    JSON.parse(response);
 will provide you with a JSON object from which you can read the properties

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following example in jsfiddle.

This is not the better way you can use JSON.parse(); or  $.parseJSON(); (jquery version)

But if this is your problem, json being returned as a string this fix it and you can alter your code

http://jsfiddle.net/dadviegas/gf8Yq/

Answer (score 0):

I think the ajax / php part should look like 
Ajax

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",   
        url: "link.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result){
             alert(result.orientation); 
        }
    });
```

PHP

```
$response=array("filename" => "$newfilename", "orientation" => "$orientation");
$response=json_encode($response);
echo $response;
```

Make sure that use at least 5.2 php version