# Can not get item of JSON-response

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, object, vue.js

I am trying to create a AJAX call - and I would like to work with the response.

This is my response I see in my browser's network console:

```
{
    "message": "success",
    "file": "dump.xml"
}
```

And this is what I want to do:

```
onComplete: function onComplete(data) {             
            var vm = this;
            console.log(data.file);
            this.$set('upload', data);
            this.$set('filename', file);

            this.modal.show();
        }
```

Okay. Well - I'm getting a response and if I write `data` to console.log, I'm getting this:

```
{"message":"success","file":"dump.xml"}
```

But if I try to do:

```
console.log(data.file);
```

I'm getting undefined. But why?

Comment: You need to parse it first then call `.file`.

Comment: where you are printing data and data.file in the code?

Comment: What are you using to make the ajax request?  Often frameworks have an option to get it to parse the response as JSON for you.

Comment: That was it. I had to tell the framework to parse the response as JSON. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON object properties are undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215736/json-object-properties-are-undefined)

Answer (score 2):

You are receiving it as a string. You have to parse it first to JSON by:

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
console.log( data.file )
```

---

**OTHER OPTION**: Or you can define it on request, add `dataType: "json"` so that you will receive json.

Like:

```
   $.ajax(
   {

      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: url,
      data: {},
      success: function( response ) {}
  }
```

Comment: no need for new `var` if using same variable name. Probably breaks in strict mode

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that `data` is a JSON string, so it will be printed in console, but when you call `data.file` it will be `undefined`. as `string` doesn't have a `file` property.

You need to parse your `data` object, before accessing `file` property:

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(data.file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your `data` will be a `JSON` string. You have parse it into an `Object` like below

```
onComplete: function onComplete(data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data)
        var vm = this;
        console.log(data.file);
        this.$set('upload', data);
        this.$set('filename', file);

        this.modal.show();
    }
```